# Elevation lines label positions (select manually?) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, elevation

[image]I have a layer of elevation lines in QGIS. Now I want to create a map that shows a certain extent of this layer and shows the labels for certain lines (ideally once for every line).
So far, this isn't a problem. However, I also want to show an inset above the main map. Now I have two problems:

1. Some labels are printed behind the inset. I can set the frequency of labels along the line from "No Repeat" (label just once per map extent) to a certain distance, however, this will result additional labels that I do not want.
2. Most lines go beyond the extent of the map I create and come back somewhere else. On the map, this will result in two lines of which QGIS will label only one. However, I cannot assume someone who looks on the map knows that those two lines belong to the same circular object.

Hence, it would be great if there was an option to set the positions of the labels along these elevation lines manually or if there was a trick to get the labels at the right positions.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing your issue(s).  Please add screenshots showing the problem(s) and what you want to attain.

Comment: I added a screenshot. I want to keep the labels with check marks, remove the label crossed out and add labels to the lines on the top left. However, the only option I see to edit the label position is the label frequency (label every x meter or every x pixels, which would, however, add a large number of labels that I don't want until I also have those I need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the option *Rendering* -> *Label every part of multi-part features*. Combined with manual adjustment of the label distances it is not perfect, but now it is at least possible to label every line >= 1 time.